# P(A ^ B ^ C) given independence of B and C

Tags: probability, independence

If you are given P(B^C) = P(B)P(C) (so B and C are independent), and you know P(A^C), P(A^B), P(A), P(B), and P(C), but A and B are dependent, and A and C are dependent, is it possible to calculate P(A^B^C)?

Since you know that B and C are independent, can you say that (A^B) and (A^C) are independent? It doesn't feel like you can, but that's the only way I can think of to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

- $B$ the result of the green die is 2 or 3
- $C$ the result of the red die is 1, or 2
- $A$ the sum of the two dice is 2, 3, or 5

  $$\begin{array}{ll:ll} A\cap B &= \{(2,1), (2,3), (3,2)\} & P(A\cap B) & =1/12\\A\cap C & = \{(1,1), (1,2), (2,1)\} & P(A\cap C) & =1/12\\A\cap B\cap C & = \{(2,1)\} & P(A\cap B\cap C) & = 1/36\end{array}$$

  - Witness $B$ and $C$ are independent events, but $A\cap B$ and $A\cap C$ are not independent events.

$\Box$

Comment: Thanks. So does that mean in general you can't say anything about P(A^B^C)?

Comment: @Dylan Not with just what you have, no.